# Tensorflow Profiler - what is this gap and how to reduce it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, profiling, tfrecord

I'm trying to understand what is happening between `EagerKernelExecute` executions (the 4th or 5th block from the top). I've looked at the profiling docs a few times, but can't figure out what that gap is.

How can I find where execution is spent?

I'm using a CPU-only setup. 16 cores, 190GB memory, 8 TFRecords loaded with tf.Data following the posted best practices.

[image]

Comment: better upload the `timeline.json`  to get more details